# Como modificar uma repetição

Tags: python

Segue o código:

```
numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))
msg1 = ('Errado')
msg2 = ('Tá osso em')
while numero != 0:
    print(msg1)
    numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))
print('Certo')
```

Como faço para que depois de 10 erros, apareça a `msg2`, sem ficar repetindo?

Answer (score 2):

Para tal, precisa de ter uma variável que vá contar o nº de vezes que o utilizador erra e uma variável para obter o novo número que o utilizador introduziu, de forma a que não perca a variável inicial.

Para fazer a confirmação segue-se o seguinte excerto de código, sendo `numero` o número inicial, `numero2` o número depois introduzido no loop e `nErros` o número de vezes que o utilizador errou em introduzir o número correto:

```
if(numero != numero2):
    nErros += 1
```

De seguida, para que possa sair do loop, pode usar a palavra `break` que quebra automáticamente o loop em que está inserida. Sabendo isso, basta verificar se o utilizador já errou `x` vezes, neste caso, 10, para que possa dar print a `msg2` e seja usada a palavra `break`:

```
if(nErros >= 10):
    print(msg2)
    break
```

Comment: E aí André, blz? Se fosse.pra interromper a msg1 só qdo aparecesse a msg2, seria com esse comando break de alguma forma?

Comment: Peço desculpa mas não entendi a sua pergunta, podia reformula-la, por favor? O comando break serve para sair de um loop, for, while ou foreach

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Glebson!

Você pode utilizar a uma variável de controle e utilizar um  para que seu loop não seja interrompido indevidamente. Como a seguir:

```
numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))
msg1 = ('Errado')
msg2 = ('Tá osso em!')
repeticao = 0
while numero != 0:
    repeticao += 1
    if repeticao == 10:
        print(msg2)
        numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))
    else:
        print(msg1)
        numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))
        pass
else:
    print('Certo')
```

.

Abraço!

Comment: E aí João blz? Massa brow. Dessa forma as duas aparecem. Tem como interromper a msg1 só quando aparece a msg2, depois volta com a primeira?

Comment: Blz, adaptei minha primeira resposta para imprimir só uma mensagem ou outra. Abrçs

Comment: Muito obrigado João 

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar essa tarefa, você precisa criar uma variável auxiliar para contar o número de voltas que o programa realizou no laço `while`, dessa forma, você consegue verificar quando a quantidade de erros chegar a 10.

Mas é claro que isso apenas não é o suficiente, pois você precisará criar uma condicional para verificar quando o número chegar a 10. Você pode então fazer o seguinte:

```
numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))

msg1 = 'Errado'
msg2 = 'Tá osso em'
cont = 0

while numero != 0:

    if cont == 10:
        print(msg2)
    else:
        print(msg1)

    cont += 1
    numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))

print('Certo')
```

Agora fica uma questão, você precisa que a mensagem apareça uma única vez ou precisa dela a cada 10 voltas ? Se for a cada 10 voltas, mude a condicional para `if cont % 10 == 0`. Exemplo:

```
while numero != 0:

    if cont % 10 == 0:  # A cada 10 voltas ele imprime a segunda mensagem.
        print(msg2)
    else:
        print(msg1)
```

Se você precisar sair do laço `while` depois da segunda mensagem, você pode utilizar a declaração `break` para encerrar a repetição.

```
while numero != 0:

    if cont == 10:
        print(msg2)
        break
    else:
        print(msg1)
```

Comment: Perfeito man, clareou a mente, valeu msm!